# Is there a maximum number of conditions allowed with Firestore rules?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a set of conditions to check if an update is allowed for documents in a given Firestore collection.

Rules are evaluated properly. My issue is that my set of conditions is becoming quite large (more than 100 conditions). Today, I added a new condition and when I tried to perform an update, I got the classic "*Missing or insufficient permissions.*".

At first, I was thinking my condition is wrong or the data used for the update is not matching the condition. However, it is satisfying the condition.

What I noticed is that whatever the condition I put, the update always fails with a permission issue. This let me think that I have too many conditions. As a quick test, I kept my new condition but removed another one and then the update pass. This seems to confirm what I thought.

The Firestore documentation mentions [quota limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#security_rules). However, my conditions are not using `exists()`, `get()`, or `getAfter()`.

Is there a limit on the number of conditions for a given operation rule?

How to check for the "*Maximum number of expressions in a ruleset*" or "*Maximum size of a ruleset*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not documented, I'm told the the limit to the number of conditions is 1000, so that's probably not a limit you're running into here.

Comment: The 1,000 expression limit is now officially documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas